# Edit the financial type of an online contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, contributions, financial-types

We have some online contribution transactions that we'd like to assign to a different Financial Type. E.g. they were assigned Donation rather than Member Dues. Is there a way to manually change the Financial Type of a completed transaction?

On a related topic, there are some combined transactions that we'd like to split: $20 -> Member Dues, $10 -> Donation instead of $30 -> Member Dues. Is it possible to edit and split these transactions across the correct Financial Types?

cheers ... :) gn

Comment: You may need to try Civi API Explorer to get these changes made - https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/#api-explorer

Answer (score 1):

I could say try price set where you will have two different Financial type - one for donation and one for membership

For the record which you wanted to correct which has been already completed - you need to delete the records and create it against manually using price set that should be the best option

I guess this helps!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the question, the Edit Line Item extension is the answer: https://civicrm.org/extensions/line-item-editor. Only a few of our transactions had to be completely deleted and recreated (they didn't understand the line item options) and since we only have about 100 to edit, the manual editing of line items is acceptable. For larger datasets, export, delete, edit and import is the only effective answer.

For editing the underlying financial type, the only method seems to be deleting the record and recreating it -

cheers ... :) gn